# Mongo DB Design For Events Calendar

Tags: mongodb

We have an events calendar and here is what I am thinking for our basic mongo schema:

users

- username
- password
- salt

events

- name
- description
- tags[]
- category
- venue_id
  ...

venues

- name
- address
- loc

Queries that will be done are:

- Listing of distinct tags (this might be hard given current design)
- events in a given tag
- Event information along with the venue location
- All event and venue information for a particular event
- All events near me. Need to use a geo index on loc

Any feedback/ideas on if we should be nesting venues inside events or use mysql instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, that looks pretty good. Let's construct some of the queries.

Assuming the collections are named users, events, venues:

- **Insert some dummy events**:

  > db.events.insert({tags:["awesome","fun","cool"]})
  >
  > db.events.insert({tags:["sweet","fun","rad"]})
- **Make an index** (like a boss)

  > db.events.ensureIndex({ tags: 1 })
- **Listing of distinct tags (this might be hard given current design)**:

  Nope, not hard.

  > db.events.distinct("tags")

  [ "awesome", "cool", "fun", "rad", "sweet" ]
- **Events in a given tag** (you meant "with a given tag" right?)

  > db.events.find({tags: "fun"})

  { "_id" : ObjectId("4ecc08c62477605df6522c97"), "tags" : [ "awesome", "fun", "cool" ] }

  { "_id" : ObjectId("4ecc08d92477605df6522c98"), "tags" : [ "sweet", "fun", "rad" ] }
- **Event information along with venue location**

  You can do this a couple different ways. One way would be to query for the event and subsequently query for the venue. With both documents, join (combine) the data you want manually.

  **OR**

  You can denormalize a bit and store cached venue names + locations (but not venue details like hours of operation, max occupancy, website, phone number, etc..) for a speed boost (1 query instead of 2) That method comes with the standard denormalization caveat of not being able to update your data in one place.
- **All event and venue information for a particular event**

  See above
- **All events near me. Need to use a geo index on loc**

  Two queries again, same concept as above just reverse the order.

  Get the venues:

  > db.venues.find( { loc : { $near : [lat,lon] } } )

  Get the events using the venue ids:

  > db.events.find( { venue : { $in : [id1,id2,id3...] } } )

Some of this stuff can be done automatically for you if you use an ODM.

Good luck!